# Why is Splash Request not Rendering

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am doing the tutorial exercise for scrapy-splash in VS Code. I cannot parse the Javascript on http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/. I have Splash running on local host 8050, I pulled it from docker with:

```
    docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode
```

scrapy-splash is installed in the root directory of the scrapy project.

The Settings.py is:

```
    SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
```

}

```
   SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
   }

   DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

   HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

I have stopped and restarted the docker image with and without private browsing enabled.I have added in a wait in the splash request and nothing. I have built the spider up from scratch and just copied in the example.

Code works fine on HTML pages but there is nothing when I use the JS version using SplashRequest. This is the "hello world" of scraping and I am really struggling to see where/ what I am doing wrong. I suspect its so dumb its obvious, but I cant see where or what I am doing wrong. I am using VS Code so perhaps there is something in my set up that is causing this but I am using a venv.

python

```
 import scrapy
 from scrape_douglas.scrape_douglas.items import QuoteItem
 from scrapy.selector import Selector
 from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class DougrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dougr'
    allowed_domains = ['toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/"]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,      endpoint='render.html')

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css("div.quote"):
        item ={'author':quote.css("small.author::text").extract_first(),
        'text':quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first(),
        'tag':quote.css("a.tag::text").extract()}
     yield item
```

This is the logfile:

```
    2019-08-14 15:08:28+0000 [-] Log opened.

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.371179 [-] Splash version: 3.3.1

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.371458 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9.2, 
    WebKit 602.1,sip 4.19.4, Twisted 18.9.0, Lua 5.2

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.371539 [-] Python 3.5.2 
    (default, Nov 12 2018,13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.371611 [-] Open files limit: 1048576

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.371658 [-] Can't bump open files limit

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.474871 [-] Xvfb is started: 
    ['Xvfb', ':920282986', '-screen', '0', 
    '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
    QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, 
    defaulting to '/tmp/runtimee-root'                                                            r

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.538650 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, 
    p roxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles                     e

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.538921 [-] memory cache: enabled, 
    private mode:o disabled, js cross-domain access: disabled

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.632635 [-] verbosity=1, slots=20, 
    argument_cach.e_max_entries=500, max-timeout=90.0

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.633557 [-] Web UI: enabled, 
    Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)nabled)

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.633904 [-] Site starting on 8050                     
    object at 0x7f75cf214

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.633998 [-] Starting factory 
    <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f75cf214cc0>

    2019-08-14 15:08:28.634273 [-] Server listening on 
    http://0.0.0.0:8050  000] "GET / HTTP/1.1"

    2019-08-14 15:52:58.379703 [-] "xxxx.xx.x.x" - - 
    [14/Aug/2019:15:52:57 +00100101 Firefox/69.0"000] 
    "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7679 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;000] 
    "GET /_ui/style.c x64; rv:69.0) 
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0"10.0; Win64; x64; rv:6

    2019-08-14 15:52:58.415976 [-] "xxx.xx.x.x" - - 
    [14/Aug/2019:15:52:57 +0000] 
    "GET /_ui/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2591 "http://localhost:8050/" 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0"
```

Comment: have u tried without proxy profiles?

Comment: Thanks @ThePyGuy - I haven't called the proxy-profiles when Istart up splash from docker. I have looked at the read the docs and cant see that there is a disable call. Is there somewhere I should be specifically looking? (apologies for the noob Qs)

Comment: sorry this is late but if i recall disabling is just not using them..